How to use custom number formatting in excel?
I have a large dataset which has been converted from .csv to .xlsx and I am having trouble with number formatting. I would like to convert values such as 258.325 and/or 1.675.305 to display 25.325 and 16.75305 (so all values have 2 digits before decimal point). Is there a custom number format formula I can use to do this?
It should be noted that I am using excel in a language where the decimal separator is ',' and thousand separator is '.' if that makes any difference.
I have tried using the formula: ?.. This only works for values with the following form: 12.345.678.

To be clear: you want te value of 258325,00 to become 25,325 and the value of 1675305,00 to become 16,75305?

Yes precisely !

I would like to convert values If you need to convert values then it's not a format thing. Format only affects at what you see but the value itself will remain untouched.  If you need to convert then @Ike 's answer is what you need. About changing decimal or thousand separator check Change the character used to separate thousands or decimals

You can't achieve this by a number format - only by recalculating the values like this:
=LEFT(A1,2) +MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)-2)/10^(LEN(A1)-2)


